# Regular expression Cannot have more than 3 letters together

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

Regular expression Cannot have more than 3 letters together (i.e. "Joe4u" is OK, but "JoeL4u" is not)
I have been trying several approaches but non of them seem to work, I have tried Lookahead and Lookbehind but nothing
This is just one of the several tries I have done.

`^(?=[A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]{0,2}[^A-Za-z]*)(?=.{8,})`

Comment: how this `"Joe4ukey"` should be considered?

Comment: Thank you...should be wrong as there are more than 3 letters together in "ukey"

Comment: Try [this](http://regexr.com/3euea)

Comment: Thank you bro that is the correct answer...but how can I give you a positive?

Comment: Could you please put an answer so that I can mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: Try this for javascript, with sub group
**/(?:[0-9])([a-z]{3})(?=[^a-z])/g**
If you are using php then you may do with **look behind** and it does not need any sub group **/(?<=[0-9])[a-z]{3}(?=[^a-z])/g**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [LIF_HKN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862058/lyf-hkn) 's answer, thanks to him for the help

```
^([A-Za-z]{0,3}[^A-Za-z]+)*[A-Za-z]{0,3}$
```

You can play with it here
[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/NxAMSC4IG-oJcyju)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `!` to reverse the test

```
if (!/[a-zA-Z]{4}/.test(str)) {
  ...
}
```

How this works step by step

- `/[a-zA-Z]{4}/.test(str)` checks if the string contains four consecutive letters
- `!...` reverses the result

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help, I just tried to test that

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help, I just tried to test that  on debuggex  but does not seem to work   https://www.debuggex.com/r/sWG1ZytwcUTY1k_8

Comment: @juniordev this is not a pure regexp, try the code in Javascript, it works in Javascript.